# Level 1 Charging Stations

Tags: electric-vehicle

These seem like basic questions about Level 1 chargers, but I cannot find the answers (possibly because everyone is rightly more interested in the Level 2 chargers.)

1. How much current will a Level 1 charger draw on a 120 V circuit?
2. Is there a substantial loss delivering power through a Level 1 charger?  (I.e., if the charger draw 20 A, does the battery receive 2.4 KW or nearly so?)
3. Is a dedicated circuit required for Level 1 chargers?
4. How long does it take to charge an Ioniq 6 SE at Level 1 rates (roughly?)

In all cases, this is in the United States, and if it matters, charging an Ioniq 6.

(For the fourth question, I keep coming across an estimate of about 18 hours for a generic "Ioniq" which might not even be an Ioniq 6.  That's what the salesman cited as well and let's just say I didn't get a warm fuzzy feeling about his technical acumen or his honesty.  I cannot find Level 1 charging estimate at a Hyundai site no matter how hard I search.)

Comment: A "how long to charge" question is dependent upon the number of miles traveled and/or the number of miles to a full charge (or 80% value). One does not typically discharge an EV to excessively low levels. When using a level one EVSE, one would desire to charge as frequently as practical, to keep durations to a low value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How much current will a Level 1 charger draw on a 120 V circuit?

The portable, plug-in-anywhere charger for the Ioniq 6 has a selectable current draw of 6, 8, 10 or 12 amps, so it's your choice. See the Ioniq 6 owner's manual page 1-30.

> Is there a substantial loss delivering power through a Level 1
> charger? (I.e., if the charger draw 20 A, does the battery receive 2.4
> KW or nearly so?)

Yes, there is a substantial loss and Level 1 is less efficient. The U.S. Department of Energy's Energy Star website claims that most Level 1, 120V AC chargers are about 70% efficient and most Level 2, 240V chargers are about 90% efficient at converting household current into miles of range. Your mileage may vary, of course.

> Is a dedicated circuit required for Level 1 chargers?

No, the plug-in-anywhere, portable, in-cable charger for the Ioniq 6 can be plugged into any 120V outlet, and it will draw 12 amps at most. If the circuit also supplies other high current devices, you can reduce the charger's amp setting to as low as 6 amps and take twice as long to charge your vehicle.

> How long does it take to charge an Ioniq 6 SE at Level 1 rates
> (roughly?)

The [2023 Ioniq 6 owner's manual](https://owners.hyundaiusa.com/content/dam/hyundai/us/myhyundai/manuals/glovebox-manual/2023/ioniq-6/2023-Ioniq-6-OM.pdf), the source of the image below, states that a Level 1 charger-in-cable that plugs into a 120V outlet takes 68 hours (3 days) to recharge the extended range battery from a 10% level up to 100%, or 46 hours 40 minutes (2 days) for the standard range battery:

[image: e]

However, as you surely know from all the research you've done, no sensible EV user would routinely discharge their vehicle to 10% and charge it to 100%. If you have a daily commute, you can calculate daily miles driven vs miles of range per hour of charging, and see if it's doable with a Level 1 charger.